# How do I set the x axis as a time axis?

Tags: pgfplots, datetime

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[scatter, only marks] table[x index=0, y index=1]{dados.txt};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With dados.txt:

```
10:30:00    37.75
08:37:00    45.19
08:36:00    52.36
12:45:00    35.00
10:07:00    36.26
10:16:00    49.50
```

How do I make the x axis with time as a variable?

Comment: That is to change the name of the axis. I don't want to change the name, I want it to recognise the hh:mm:ss format and display the data.

Comment: \pgfparsetime (see TikZ manual page 1212).  pgfplotatable can perform the conversion and create a new column with decimal values.

Comment: See also `table[x expr={...}]` (pgfplots manual page 60).